# How can I identify this silver kitchen fork?

Tags: identification

[image: Fork handle showing maker's marks]Can somebody help me identify this kitchen silver fork. Searching in internet, but not found anything...

Comment: Anything helpful here? http://www.silvercollection.it/englishsilverhallmarks.html

Comment: Do you have any idea which country it's from?

Comment: @shoover Looking there, but not find anything similar.

Comment: @called2voyage No, i found it when throw out all unused tools from barn.

Comment: @AnyMan Ok, I worried that may be the case. Could make it hard to pin down.

Comment: Some GPs here: http://www.silvercollection.it/englishsilvermarksXGPPP.html and AKs here: http://www.silvercollection.it/englishsilvermarksXAKKK.html

Comment: @AllInOne It's different

Comment: Found in Latvia?

Comment: @AllInOne Yes..

Comment: Voting to close. I know it's old and answered but this is off-topic and invites more irrelevant content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I found.
[There](https://www.925-1000.com/silverplate_K.html)

[image]

It's Alexander Kach.
Looks similar to that, what I have.

Comment: Good find. Welcome to the site

Comment: Looks like a match! By the way, you can accept your own answer. :)

Comment: This puts the fork at no less than 100 years old, if the dates in that snippet are right!